# Flume to Kafka to Elasticsearch Integration

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, flume

I am passing some data from Flume to Kafka. My Flafka config file looks like this:

```
 tier1.sources  = source1
 tier1.channels = channel1
 tier1.sinks    = sink1

 tier1.sources.source1.type = exec
 tier1.sources.source1.command = cat /testing.txt
 tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1

 tier1.channels.channel1.type   = memory
 tier1.channels.channel1.capacity = 10000
 tier1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000


 tier1.sinks.sink1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
 tier1.sinks.sink1.topic = sink1
 tier1.sinks.sink1.brokerList = kafkagames-1:9092,kafkagames-2:9092
 tier1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
 tier1.sinks.sink1.batchSize = 20
```

And I have connected Kafka and Elasticsearch using [kafka river plugin](https://github.com/mariamhakobyan/elasticsearch-river-kafka). FLume source is sending data to Kafka Consumer whereas Elasticsearch is expecting data from Kafka Producer.

Is there a way I can push the data to Kafka Producer from Flume rather than directly going to Kafka Consumer so Elasticsearch can read the data?

Any advice? Thanks.